How to pass data from one React component to another?
Being very new to React, I am having a hard time in passing the data across to other components from the parent component<App.js>. I am sharing the code below for reference. My goal is to pass the variable stocksName to other components such as Stocks.js where currently it is not being recognized. Any help would be highly appreciated.
App.js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-dropdown-select';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css'
import StocksView from './components/Stocks'

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [stocksName, setStocksName] = useState([]);
  const [selectvalue, setselectvalue] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(selectvalue);
    axios.post("./getStocks", selectvalue)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        const nodeData = JSON.parse(response.data.nodeData);
        setStocksName(nodeData.STOCKS_NAME);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/listPartitions")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((partition) => {
        const parsed = JSON.parse(partition.nodePartition);
        const partitions = Object.entries(parsed).map(([key, value]) => ({
          label: value,
          value: key
        }));

        // put the partitions data in the state
        setData(partitions);
        console.log(parsed, partitions);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Select
          name="select"
          options={data}
          multi
          onChange={(selected) => setselectvalue(selected.map((item) => item.label))
          }
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <div className="message">{message ? <p>{message}</p> : null}</div>
      </form>
      <div>
        <StocksView/>
      </div>
    </div>

  )
}

export default App;

Stocks.js
import React from 'react'
import Graph from 'react-vis-network-graph'

export default function StocksView() {
    const stocks = {
        nodes: [
            {stocksName}
        ]
    }
    
     return (
    <div className='container'>
        <Stocks 
            stocks={stocks}
        />
    </div>
  )


To pass data from parent component to children components, you can pass it as Props, please refer https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component

Mate, please just google it next time. This are the basics. Now, related to the problem, @dinhit showed you the docs. READ THEM! About passing the data between components, think of it very simple, you just say in the parameters of the component function what you want to pass, then you just pass the variables as the value for the parameters like HTML attributes, when you call the component, thats all! Hope it helped.

To pass the stocksName variable from the App component to the StocksView component, you can simply pass it as a prop.
Another way to achieve this is by creating a global store, which is a more advanced method suitable for managing a lot of state. But, as of now you can proceed with concept of props (Check here)
Here, is how you can do this with props.
App.js:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Select from 'react-dropdown-select';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css'
import StocksView from './components/Stocks'

function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [stocksName, setStocksName] = useState([]);
  const [selectvalue, setSelectValue] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(selectvalue);
    axios.post("./getStocks", selectvalue)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        const nodeData = JSON.parse(response.data.nodeData);
        setStocksName(nodeData.STOCKS_NAME);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/listPartitions")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((partition) => {
        const parsed = JSON.parse(partition.nodePartition);
        const partitions = Object.entries(parsed).map(([key, value]) => ({
          label: value,
          value: key
        }));

        // put the partitions data in the state
        setData(partitions);
        console.log(parsed, partitions);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Select
          name="select"
          options={data}
          multi
          onChange={(selected) => setSelectValue(selected.map((item) => item.label))
          }
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <div className="message">{message ? <p>{message}</p> : null}</div>
      </form>
      <div>
        <StocksView stocksName={stocksName}/> {/* Passing stocksName as prop */}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;

Stocks.js:
import React from 'react'
import Graph from 'react-vis-network-graph'

export default function StocksView({ stocksName }) { // Accepting stocksName as a prop
    const stocks = {
        nodes: [
            {stocksName}
        ]
    }
    
     return (
    <div className='container'>
        <Graph // I suppose you meant to use Graph here instead of Stocks
            stocks={stocks}
        />
    </div>
  )
}

Now, stocksName from the App component will be passed to the StocksView component as a prop and can be accessed within StocksView as stocksName.
Let me know, if you've any questions :(

You can use Context.Provider
I have the same problem a few days ago
This helped me so much https://es.react.dev/reference/react/createContext
With Context you can use your variables in all your components

Props are arguments passed into React components.
Read this: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_props.asp

This answer does not provide a solution to the asker's query. If you elect to answer, please provide a complete answer that includes a solution with supporting information, otherwise leave a comment. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer
